# TensorFlow consistently achieves smaller error than PyTorch for the same network, loss and initialization

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I have two implementations of same network for CIFAR10 in TensorFlow and PyTorch. Both have weight initializations from the same distributions (for weights - xiavier uniform and zeros for biases) but TensorFlow seems to consistently outperform PyTorch in terms of minimal test error (although PyTorch appears to be almost `9%` faster!). Both are optimized using SGD. Even if equipped with exactly the same initialization values TensorFlow still achieves smaller error. These are  typical curves from the simulations:
[image]
*The red curve is test-error of TensorFlow and orange curve is a test-error of PyTorch. Both had been initialized with the exact same values.*

Since the code is relatively long, I provide here only implementations of architectures. The full reproducible code for both implementations in Jupyter format could be found [here, on GitHub](https://github.com/vlad-user/tf_vs_torch).

TF implementation of network:

```
def tf_model(graph, init=None):
    with graph.as_default():
        if init:
            conv1_init = init['conv1']
            conv2_init = init['conv2']
            logits_init = init['logits']
            conv1_init = tf.constant_initializer(conv1_init)
            conv2_init = tf.constant_initializer(conv2_init)
            logits_init = tf.constant_initializer(logits_init)
        else:
            conv1_init = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
            conv2_init = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
            logits_init = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()

        with tf.name_scope('Input'):
            x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 32, 32, 3], name='x')
            y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None], name='y')
            keep_prob = tf.placeholder_with_default(1.0 - dropout_rate, shape=())
        with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
            with tf.name_scope('conv1'):
                conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(x,
                                         filters=6,
                                         kernel_size=5,
                                         strides=1,
                                         padding='valid',
                                         kernel_initializer=conv1_init,
                                         bias_initializer=tf.initializers.zeros,
                                         activation=tf.nn.relu,
                                         name='conv1'
                                         )


                max_pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(value=conv1,
                                           ksize=(1, 2, 2, 1),
                                           strides=(1, 2, 2, 1),
                                           padding='SAME',
                                           name='max_pool1')

                dropout1 = tf.nn.dropout(max_pool1, keep_prob=keep_prob)

            with tf.name_scope('conv2'):
                conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(dropout1,
                                         filters=12,
                                         kernel_size=3,
                                         strides=1,
                                         padding='valid',
                                         bias_initializer=tf.initializers.zeros,
                                         activation=tf.nn.relu,
                                         kernel_initializer=conv2_init,
                                         name='conv2')

                max_pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(value=conv2,
                                           ksize=(1, 2, 2, 1),
                                           strides=(1, 2, 2, 1),
                                           padding='VALID',
                                           name='max_pool2')

                dropout2 = tf.nn.dropout(max_pool2, keep_prob=keep_prob)

            with tf.name_scope('logits'):
                flatten = tf.layers.Flatten()(max_pool2)
                logits = tf.layers.dense(flatten,
                                         units=10,
                                         kernel_initializer=logits_init,
                                         bias_initializer=tf.initializers.zeros,
                                         name='logits')

    return x, y, keep_prob, logits
```

PyTorch implementation:

```
class TorchModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dropout_rate=0.0, init=None):
        super(TorchModel, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3,
                      out_channels=6,
                      kernel_size=5,
                      padding=0,
                      bias=True),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
            nn.Dropout(p=dropout_rate))
        if init:
            conv1_init = init['conv1']
            self.conv1[0].weight = nn.Parameter(torch.FloatTensor(conv1_init))
        else:
            torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.conv1[0].weight)
        torch.nn.init.zeros_(self.conv1[0].bias)
        self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=6,
                      out_channels=12,
                      kernel_size=3,
                      bias=True),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
            nn.Dropout(p=dropout_rate))
        if init:
            conv2_init = init['conv2']
            self.conv2[0].weight = nn.Parameter(torch.FloatTensor(conv2_init))
        else:
            torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.conv2[0].weight)
        torch.nn.init.zeros_(self.conv2[0].bias)

        self.logits = nn.Linear(432, 10)
        if init:
            logits_init = init['logits']
            logits_init = np.reshape(logits_init, [10, 432])
            self.logits.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.FloatTensor(logits_init))
        else:
            torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.logits.weight)
        torch.nn.init.zeros_(self.logits.bias)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.logits(x)
        return x
```

I also would like to add that the reason that I'm asking is that for different optimization algorithm (which is very complicated therefore I provide here a simple example with SGD) that I currently testing, the opposite happens - PyTorch is consistently better than TF in terms of minimal error.

I would glad to hear what your thoughts are. Did you have the same experience? Do I miss something in implementations of SGD in TensorFlow and in PyTorch?

Thank you.

Comment: I have experience with tensorflow but not pytorch, so I googled around and found some generally similar complaints. You may gain some insight by looking here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/the-same-model-produces-worse-results-on-pytorch-than-on-tensorflow/5380/8 where someone mentions that he ran pytorch on CPU instead of GPU, or here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7624 where tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected is mentioned as a possible culprit, as well as differences in double precision.

Comment: @InonPeled Thank you! I'll take a look.

Comment: I would suggest to use the same seed for weight initializations for a comparison of this sort. In TF, it would be `tf.random.set_random_seed` and for PyTorch it is `torch.manual_seed`.